# labels dimension or rotate python seaborn graphs

Tags: python, pandas, graph, seaborn

I would like to fix label problems in a seaborn graph, I have more than 30 items in the x axis. How to reduce the label dimension or may be rotate the graph?

[image]

```
import seaborn as sns
g = sns.factorplot(x="target", data=df3, kind="count",
                   palette="BuPu", size=6, aspect=1.5)
```

Comment: Are you after `plt.xticks(rotation=90)`? (where `import matplotlib.pylab as plt`)

Comment: You can also try: `g.set(xticks=np.arange(0, N, 3))` to show only every third label.

Comment: I have added both import matplotlib.pylab as plt and the other statement (plt.xticks(rotation=90) but nothing changes....may os it in any particular order?

Comment: What environment do you work in?

Answer (score 2):

This will work if executed in a single cell in Jupyter:

```
g = sns.factorplot(x="target", data=df3, kind="count",
                   palette="BuPu", size=6, aspect=1.5)
g.set(xticks=np.arange(0, 40, 3))  # or however many you have
plt.xticks(rotation=90);
```

It will also work if executed as one block in Spyder.